# How to use grep negatively?

Tags: grep

I want to do the opposite of what grep does. I want to excludes the output lines with a certain pattern.

**What I wish to have is a command "ngrep":**

```
$ output
hi how are you?
hi hi haw are you?
hu hi how are you?
haw haw haw are you?

$ output | ngrep 'haw' :
hi how are you?
hu hi how are you?
```

Comment: `awk '!/haw/' file`...

Answer (score 7):

From `grep` [*man page*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

Comment: oh damn! I didn't know when I search the manpage with `/` it is case insensitive! I had already searched for -v and thought it was about the version but that is -V!